# How to check if datatable has any row containing a string and get row index of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table in my html with columns username and password. how can I get index of the row which has username="abc" using jquery in my javascript?

```
var myTable = document.getElementById('usersTable');
```

Comment: `$('tr td:eq(INDEX_OF_USERNAME_COLUMN):contains("abc")').index()`

Comment: How can I refer my datatable? `myTable` . I want this index to be in a variable.

Comment: Just assign it to a variable then! Rayon has given you the answer.

Comment: I wanted to know where can I specify my datatable name here. :)

Comment: `$('#usersTable tr td:eq(INDEX_OF_USERNAME_COLUMN):contains("abc")').index()` this is how you assign your table id

Comment: Thanks. My table is generated by ajax and has pagination hence it is just looking in the 1st 10 rows visible on my HTML page . Because of this I am getting  -1 index for any text not on the 1st page of the table.

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter()` function. Don't use `:contains` if you are looking for exact match.

```
$allRows = $('#usersTable tr');
row = $allRows.filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).find('td').eq(INDEX_OF_USERNAME_COLUMN).text()) == "abc";
});
index = $allRows.index(row);
```

Comment: @Rayon Oh yes. I missed that.

Comment: Thanks . How can I specify my table name which has to be filtered. `myTable = document.getElementById('usersTable');`

Comment: I got this error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).ed` is not a function

Comment: Aah thanks missed that. I am getting index = -1 even though I have the text in the table column. My first column has checkbox and 2nd has username   return $.trim($(this).find('td').eq(1).text()) == usersUpdated[i].username; . console.log(usersUpdated[i].username) gives me correct value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110381/discussion-between-rejith-r-krishnan-and-love2code).